# Android - Content Values inserted duplicate 4 times

Tags: android

For some reason when I try to insert multiple data I get 4 duplicates of each row. I tried cv.clear(), and I also tried cv = new ContentValues() but I don't know what is causing it to insert 4 times. The for loop certainly only runs twice and it calls db.insert twice. But I think it is something to do with the ContentValues that I don't see.

In MainActivity.java

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();    

String[] skuArray = { "1234", "4569" };
String[] nameArray = { "Something", "Anything" };
String[] descriptionArray = { "It is something", "It is anything" };
String[] costArray = { "$5.00", "$10.00"};
for (int i = 0; i < skuArray.length; i++) {
    String sku = skuArray[i];
    String name = nameArray[i];
    String description = descriptionArray[i];
    String cost = costArray[i];     
    db.insert(sku, name, description, cost;
}
```

In DBAdapter.java insert() method

```
public void insert(String sku, String name, String description, String cost) {
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        // Insert into ITEM_TABLE
        cv.put(ITEM_SKU, sku);
        cv.put(ITEM_NAME, name);
        cv.put(ITEM_DESCRIPTION, description);
        db.insert(ITEM_TABLE, null, cv);

        // Insert into PRICE_TABLE
        cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PRICE_SKU, sku);
        cv.put(PRICE_COST, cost);
        db.insert(PRICE_TABLE, null, cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

DBAdapter.java loadAllItemsQuery() method

```
public void loadAllItemsQuery() {
    try {
        String SELECT_ITEM_QUERY = "SELECT " + ITEM_SKU + ", " + ITEM_NAME + ", " + ITEM_DESCRIPTION + ", " + PRICE_COST + " FROM " + ITEM_TABLE + " INNER JOIN " + PRICE_TABLE;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_ITEM_QUERY, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {
            skuArray[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(0);
            nameArray[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(1);
            descriptionArray[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(2);
            priceArray[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(3);

            Log.d("loadAllItemsQuery()", "Count row: " + cursor.getCount());
            Log.d("loadAllItemsQuery()", "Current row position: " +  cursor.getPosition());
            Log.d("loadAllItemsQuery()", skuArray[cursor.getPosition()]);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 

        cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Count row: 8
Current row position: 0
sku: 1234
Count row: 8
Current row position: 1
sku: 1234
Count row: 8
Current row position: 2
sku: 1234
Count row: 8
Current row position: 3
sku: 1234
Count row: 8
Current row position: 4
sku: 4569
Count row: 8
Current row position: 5
sku: 4569
Count row: 8
Current row position: 6
sku: 4569
Count row: 8
Current row position: 7
sku: 4569
```

Comment: Where do `PRICE_SKU` and `ITEM_SKU` values come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be with your join, causing it to return each sku 4 times.

Try this:

```
String SELECT_ITEM_QUERY = "SELECT DISTINCT " + ITEM_SKU + ", " + ITEM_NAME + ", " + ITEM_DESCRIPTION + ", " + PRICE_COST + " FROM " + ITEM_TABLE + " INNER JOIN " + PRICE_TABLE;
```

Better option: look into the query and frame it more appropriately rather than selecting distinct.  Also try to print all your arrays. If there is a difference in values in other fields you'll still continue to get more than expected rows. **AND** check if your data is sane. Query might be correct but data might also cause issues.

Comment: Do share what was causing it.